# Java Histogram won't display all asterisks?

Tags: java, arraylist, histogram

I am doing a project where I take book ratings from a file, sort them by rating, and then create a histogram of asterisks for each rating. So basically if the list contains ratings from 3.8 to 4.6, the histogram displays 3.7 to 4.7 with asterisks for each book rated by that one. I have to print the labels and then the asterisks, and I've tried everything it seems and nothing is working to display all the stars. Every time I run it, only one asterisk prints after one rating so I'm not sure what the issue is! I would appreciate all the help I can get!

```
public static void histogram(ArrayList <Double> theList) {
System.out.println("Histogram of Amazon Bestseller Ratings");
System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
double num = theList.get(0) - 0.10;
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for (double i = num; i < theList.get(theList.size() - 1) + 0.10; i += 0.10) { //iterate thru labels
    System.out.printf("%.1f ", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < theList.size(); ++j) { // iterates thru list of ratings
            if (theList.get(j) == i) {
                System.out.print("*");
                }
            }
        System.out.println();
        }
      System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
       }`
```